# Can I fully automate Docker deployment of a .Net CoreCLR on a CI Server without installing Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, docker

I'm experimenting with the deployment of ASP.Net 5 CoreCLR apps to Linux Docker containers. Literally all the articles, posts, etc. I found involve using the Visual Studio GUI. On publish a PowerShell script gets created, which I believe I could re-use on a CI server. But this script itself seems to depend on an installed VS14 including the Docker extension:

```
function Ensure-DockerCommand {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param()
    process {
        if (! (Get-Command docker -errorAction SilentlyContinue))
        {
            $vsInstallPath = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" -Name InstallDir | select -ExpandProperty InstallDir)
            if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($env:ProgramW6432)) {
                $vsKeyPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0"
            }
            else {
                $vsKeyPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0"
            }

            $vsInstallPath = (Get-ItemProperty $vsKeyPath -Name InstallDir | select -ExpandProperty InstallDir)
            $dockerExtensionPath = Join-Path $vsInstallPath "Extensions\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools\Docker"
            $env:Path = "$dockerExtensionPath;" + $env:Path
        }
    }
}
```

Has anybody managed to do this without installing Visual Studio on a build server?

Or do you think this question is premature, because support for this is just not available *yet*. I can't find any relevant documentation.

Comment: My impression from that script is that Visual Studio simply bundled the dockers tools in an extension. If you install them stand-alone from the docker Website, you may be able to call them directly to create your docker images. Most of the docker tools seems to require a Linux VM to run in the background however. Want you want to do is certainly possible, but you really are on the bleeding edge of new technologie. You may have to do a lot by yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't need Visual Studio installed. You don't even need DNVM or DNX installed or run in a Windows environment. You do however need the Docker client and access to a Docker host.

Here are some instructions on how to build and run ASP.Net 5 Docker images:
[Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/running-asp-net-5-applications-in-linux-containers-with-docker/)

The gist of it is that you create a Dockerfile in the root of your project:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dnu", "restore"]

EXPOSE 5004
ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "-p", "project.json", "kestrel"]
```

And then simply issue the Docker build command:

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

And then you run it:

```
docker run -t -d -p 80:5004 myapp
```

The default ASP.Net image uses the Mono runtime, but if you want to use the CoreCLR runtime you can simply specify a tag in the FROM statement:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-beta8-coreclr
```

See the aspnet-docker repository for updated information on what tags are available: https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker

Comment: Does anyone know how to update this for RC2?